# is SQLite not exists thread-safe?

Tags: sqlite, concurrency

Will this throw a constraint violation error if column url had a unique constraint on it on SQLite and this executed concurrently? meaning two or more threads running the exact same insert at the same time.

```
insert into urls(url) 
select 'https://www.test.com' 
where not exists(select * from urls where url = 'https://www.test.com');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQLite will enforce the unique constraint correctly, even when faced with concurrent updates. So one of these transactions might fail when they are executed at the exact same time.